# Use partial in flash message

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my ActionController I have the following:

```
    format.html { 
      flash[:notice] = "Success" 
      redirect_to @event 
    }
```

However, I want to use a partial for the flash notice. I tried using `render :partial` but this gave me double render errors. Any ideas if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `render_to_string`  This should let you render a partial a string without getting a double render error.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone wondering, the message becomes: `flash[:notice] = render_to_string :partial => "success"`

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages partial code

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="messages">
    <div class="message-container">
      <% flash.each_with_index do |(k,v),i| %>
        <div id="message-<%= i %>" class="actual-message  alert-<%= k.to_s.sub('_stay', '') %>">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" style="float:right">x</a>
            <% if v.is_a?(Array) %>
              <ul>
                <% v.each do |vv| %>
                  <li><%= vv %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            <% else %>
              <%= raw v %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

render in your application.html.erb using

"layouts/flash_messages" %>